# How to draw a triangule impulse by Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am drawing the graph for the lecture "Signals and Systems", and I want to draw the impulse.

My code as below

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\hspace*{-0.1\linewidth}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={$2 = x_{o}(t)$}]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot] coordinates
    {(-2,0) (0,2)  (2,0)} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what `\hspace*{-0.1\linewidth}` is good for (does it have an effect?) and you do not need pgfplots for that.

Comment: Try e.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,-latex] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[above left]{$t$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,-0.1) -- (0,1.5) node[below left]{$x(t)$};
\draw[blue,very thick] (-1,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,0);
\foreach \X in {-1,0,1}
{\draw (\X,0) -- ++(0,-0.1) node[below]{$\X$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. There are countless possibilities and what is the optimal way to go will depend on what you intend to do with this graph,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `pgfplots` is for such simple diagram overkill, however for other more demanding diagrams can be very handy. to obtain showed images in your question, you need define more options for `axis`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=54mm,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=center,
xmin = -1.2,    xmax = 1.2,
ymax =  1.2,
xtick={-1, 0, 1},
ytick={1},
xlabel={$t$},
every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},anchor=south east},
ylabel={$x(t)$}
            ]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none] coordinates
    {(-1,0) (0,1)  (1,0)} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

for this particular diagram is simpler use pure `tikz`, for example as suggest [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) in his comment.